# Match multiple spaces and special chars with regex: possible to shorten this regex?

Tags: regex

I match multiple spaces and some special chars with the following regex:

```
(?:\s{2,}|\!|\@|\#|\$|\€|\£|\%|\^|\&|\*|\(|\)|\,|\.|\?|\"|\:|\{|\}|\||\<|\>|\\)
```

Is it possible to shorten this expression in any way? Maybe somebody see a variant without a need to divide chars with a pipe?

Strange, that this expression `(\s{2,}|[!@#$€£%^&*(),.?":{}|<>§\\])` works in  https://www.regextester.com/, but not in https://regexr.com/

Comment: They match the exact same thing when I try it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `|` *and* a character class together like this:

`/(?:\s{2,}|[!@#$€£%\^&\*\(\),\.?"\:\{\}\|\<\>\\§])/`

I also removed most of the backslashes as only a few of the characters need to be escaped.